Open3D 0.18.0, numpy 2.0.2 and pyrealsense2 compatibility issue with segfault
I'm facing a strange issue when working with Open3D 0.18.0, numpy 2.0.2, and pyrealsense2. I'm getting a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when trying to create a point cloud from a depth image obtained using pyrealsense2.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import pyrealsense2 as rs

# Configure RealSense pipeline
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
pipeline.start(config)

# Wait for a frame
frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()

# Convert depth frame to Open3D image
depth_o3d = o3d.geometry.Image(np.asarray(depth_frame.get_data()))

# Intrinsic parameters
depth_intrin = depth_frame.profile.as_video_stream_profile().intrinsics
width, height = depth_intrin.width, depth_intrin.height
intrinsic = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(width, height, 
                                                  depth_intrin.fx, depth_intrin.fy, 
                                                  depth_intrin.ppx, depth_intrin.ppy)

# Attempt to create point cloud
depth_o3d = o3d.geometry.Image(depth_image)
depth_array = np.asarray(depth_o3d)
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_depth_image(depth_o3d, intrinsic)

voxel_size = 0.05
voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size=voxel_size)

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_grid])

pipeline.stop()

And the data about pcd:
depth_array shape: (480, 640)
depth_o3d data type: <class 'open3d.cuda.pybind.geometry.Image'>
depth_o3d content: Image of size 640x480, with 1 channels.
Use numpy.asarray to access buffer data.
intrinsic width: 640
intrinsic height: 480
intrinsic fx: 590.2589111328125
intrinsic fy: 590.2589111328125

I've already checked that my memory usage is only around 30%, so it doesn't seem to be a memory issue. I've also ensured that all the libraries are properly installed.
I'm using Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04. Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this segfault or how to troubleshoot it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Try downgrading numpy to version 1.x.y. Recently noticed these Open3D errors increase since numpy v2.0.0 is backward incompatible.

@saurabheights Thank you! I downgrading numpy to 1.22.4 and it works.

Your welcome :)
